# How do I shorten my code by using loops or goto in this case?

Tags: loops, batch-file, goto

I'm new to batch file and this seems like a stupid question for someone who knows a little bit about batch file but I just can't achieve the desired outcome using the way I would do in C++ or other programming. What I was trying to do is to randomly store three 1s into the elements for each of the 2x2 arrays. Thanks in advance. The full code is below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem ========Creating four 2x2 zero arrays
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
    for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
        for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
            set map[%%x][%%y][%%z]=0
        )
    )
)
rem ========Putting three 1s in elements randomly **(How do I shorten this part?)**
set /a count=3
:while0
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a sth=map[!i!][!j!][0]
    if !sth! EQU 0 (
        set map[!i!][!j!][0]=1
        set /a count-=1
    )
    if not !count! EQU 0 GOTO while0
set /a count=3
:while1
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a sth=map[!i!][!j!][1]
    if !sth! EQU 0 (
        set map[!i!][!j!][1]=1
        set /a count-=1
    )
    if not !count! EQU 0 GOTO while1
set /a count=3
:while2
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a sth=map[!i!][!j!][2]
    if !sth! EQU 0 (
        set map[!i!][!j!][2]=1
        set /a count-=1
    )
    if not !count! EQU 0 GOTO while2
set /a count=3
:while3
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a sth=map[!i!][!j!][3]
    if !sth! EQU 0 (
        set map[!i!][!j!][3]=1
        set /a count-=1
    )
    if not !count! EQU 0 GOTO while3
rem ========Result
echo !map[0][0][0]!!map[1][0][0]!
echo !map[0][1][0]!!map[1][1][0]!
echo.
echo.
echo !map[0][0][1]!!map[1][0][1]!
echo !map[0][1][1]!!map[1][1][1]!
echo.
echo.
echo !map[0][0][2]!!map[1][0][2]!
echo !map[0][1][2]!!map[1][1][2]!
echo.
echo.
echo !map[0][0][3]!!map[1][0][3]!
echo !map[0][1][3]!!map[1][1][3]!
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem ========Creating four 2x2 one arrays
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
    for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
        for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
            set map[%%x][%%y][%%z]=1
        )
    )
)

rem ========Putting one 0 in an element randomly
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set map[!i!][!j!][%%z]=0
)

rem ========Result
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
   echo !map[0][0][%%z]!!map[1][0][%%z]!
   echo !map[0][1][%%z]!!map[1][1][%%z]!
   echo/
   echo/
)

pause
```

**EDIT**: New version to fulfill the *new requirement* of variable number of zeros.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem ========Creating four 2x2 arrays using three 1s and one 0 to populate each
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
    set "digits=1110" & set "num=4"
    for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
        for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
            rem Get a random number between 0 and "num"
            set /A ran=!random!%%num, ranP1=ran+1, num-=1
            rem Use it to extract a random digit from "digits"
            for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("!ran! !ranP1!") do (
                set "map[%%x][%%y][%%z]=!digits:~%%i,1!"
                set "digits=!digits:~0,%%i!!digits:~%%j!"
            )
        )
    )
)

rem ========Result
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
   echo !map[0][0][%%z]!!map[1][0][%%z]!
   echo !map[0][1][%%z]!!map[1][1][%%z]!
   echo/
   echo/
)

pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what if there is more than one zero?

Comment: In such a case, then it is a _different question_ **`;)`** See my edit...

Comment: So? Did my new code solved your problem? If so, then you may select this as Best Answer via the green check mark...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem ========Creating four 2x2 zero arrays
:restart
for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
    for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
        for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
            set map[%%x][%%y][%%z]=0
        )
    )
)
:: loading array randomly with 1s
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,3) DO (
 SET /a x=!random! %% 2, y=!random! %% 2, z=!random! %% 4
 for /l %%z in (0,1,3) do (
  for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
   for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
    IF %%z==!z! IF %%y==!y! IF %%x==!x! (
     IF !map[%%x][%%y][%%z]! == 1 GOTO restart
     SET /a map[%%x][%%y][%%z]=1
    )
   )
  )
 )
)
:: display
FOR /L %%z IN (0,1,3) DO (
 FOR /L %%y IN (0,1,1) DO ECHO !map[0][%%y][%%z]!!map[1][%%y][%%z]!
 ECHO.
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The middle block sets the number of 1s to insert. Three random numbers are then chosen and assigned to `x`,`y` and `z` and the three nested `for/L` commands simply set `%%x..%%z` to each possible value combination of `x..z`, but in a `metaviariable` for convenience. When the loops select the correct combination, that point on the map is tested. If it's `1`, start all over again. If not, set it to `1`.

The display routine seems obvious.

Comment: What I was trying to do is to randomly store three 1s into each of the 2x2 arrays so there should be twelve 1s but it seems your code generates only three 1s in total and it looks like it will take a long time to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Aacini's code shortened a little, *(due to title text)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem ========Creating four 2x2 one arrays
For /L %%A In (0 1 3) Do For /L %%B In (0 1 1) Do For /L %%C In (0 1 1
) Do Set "m[%%C%%B%%A]=1"

Rem ========Putting one 0 in an element randomly
For /L %%A in (0 1 3
) Do Set/A B=!Random!%%2,C=!Random!%%2&Set "m[!B!!C!%%A]=0")

Rem ========Result
For /L %%A In (0 1 3
) Do Echo !m[00%%A]!!m[10%%A]!&Echo !m[01%%A]!!m[11%%A]!&Echo(&Echo(

Pause
```

*Please don't accept this answer in preference over theirs*